# ASP.NET Routing Problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes

I am using this method in almost all my applications but now it shows me a System.FormatException in mscorlib.dll

global.asax

```
routes.MapPageRoute("Page/{ParameterId}", "Url/{ParameterId}", "~/Backend/Page.aspx");
```

code-behind

```
if (Page.RouteData.Values["ParameterId"] == null) return;
var Parameter = Page.RouteData.Values["ParameterId"].ToString();
```

as soon as I try to initialize "Parameter" I get the Exception.
Debugger shows me that the "Page.RouteData.Values" is accessible but my variable still remains null.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `request context`

```
var parameterId=HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["ParameterId"]
```

OR:

in action

```
public ActionResult Action(string ParameterId)
{
   /// do something
}
```